# C++ member function with iterator as parameter

Tags: c++, templates, functor

I'd like to write a class `test` that is able to store a function that is able to iterate through a collection of elements identified by the classic `[first,last)` iterator pair, that is:

```
template <typename T>
struct sum
{
  template <typename I>
  T operator()(I first, I last) const
  {
    T res = 0;
    while (first != last)
    {
      res += *first;
      ++first;
    }
    return res;
  }
};
//...
int main()
{
  test<double> t;
  t.set(sum<double>);
  double a[] {1.,2.,3.};
  std::cout << "Test (array) => " << t.call(a, a+3) << std::endl;
  std::vector<double> v {1.,2.,3.};
  std::cout << "Test (vector) => " << t.call(v.begin(), v.end()) << std::endl;
  std::list<double> l {1.,2.,3.};
  std::cout << "Test (list) => " << t.call(l.begin(), l.end()) << std::endl;
}
```

I thought to use `std::function`, but I've failed to do this as I wasn't able to declare the templated iterator pair.
A possible workaround is the following, which however only works with plain arrays (e.g., `double[]` or `double*`, like the above variable `a`), but not with other containers (e.g., like the above variables `v` and `l`):

```
template <typename T>
class test
{
public:
  template <typename F>
  void set(F f)
  {
    f_ = f;
  }
  template <typename I>
  T call(I first, I last) const
  {
    return f_(first, last);
  }
private:
  std::function<T(T*,T*)> f_;
};
```

Any idea on how can I get the correct behavior?

NOTE: I'm compiling with GCC 4.9.2 --std=c++11

Thank you very much.

Comment: I don't think it's possible to store a type-erased functor that takes two iterators and returns a `T`. The only way I could think of to implement that would require a virtual template method... which isn't allowed.

Comment: I changed my mind :)

Comment: I've edited your question to take out your answer (it's not appropriate for the question - you could potentially post it as an answer separately). But it's also not a very good solution since (a) now you're imposing potentially huge runtime overhead and (b) adding artificial requirements on `T` (that it be copyable).

Comment: OK. I put the answer there since I didn't want to answer my question by myself, but I only wanted to know opinions about it. Thank you very much for the clarification. Also, thank you very much for your opinion (especially for the issue (b)).

Comment: Moved the update as a new answer. Thanks @Barry for pointing it out

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you want is really to be able to construct a:

```
std::function<T(FwdIter<T>, FwdIter<T>)>
```

where `FwdIter<T>` is some type-erased class that satsifes the ForwardIterator concept and is dereferenced to a `T`. For that, check out the [Boost.TypeErasure](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_57_0/doc/html/boost_typeerasure.html) library, where we can do:

```
#include <boost/type_erasure/any.hpp>
#include <boost/type_erasure/operators.hpp>
#include <boost/mpl/vector.hpp>

using namespace boost::type_erasure;

template <typename T>
using FwdIter = any<
    boost::mpl::vector<
        copy_constructible<>,
        incrementable<>,
        dereferenceable<T>,
        equality_comparable<>
    >>;
```

With that and your definition of `sum`, I can do:

```
std::function<int(FwdIter<int>, FwdIter<int>)> f = sum<int>{};
std::vector<int> v = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5};

std::cout << f(v.begin(), v.end()) << std::endl; // prints 15
```

In your `test<T>`, you could just have a `std::function<T(FwdIter<T>, FwdIter<T>)>` member as desired.

Comment: Wow! Very clever. Thank you very much. I'm working to an alternative solution too (I'm going to write it as a new post below). But I think your answer is more elegant.

Comment: I've added the alternative solution as an update to the original post. Any comment is welcome :)

Answer (score 1):

I've tried to work on an alternative solution.

Essentially, the user function is wrapped inside a holder holder which fix the function signature to `T(const std::vector<T>&)`. With respect to @Barry's solution (the one I've accepted), this doesn't require external libraries. However it suffers of performance issues due to the construction of the vector object at runtime. Also, and more importantly, as pointed out by @Barry, this solution imposes artificial requirements on `T` (like `T` must be copyable).

Here is it:

```
template <typename T,typename F>
class holder
{
public:
    holder(F f) : f_(f) { }

    T operator()(const std::vector<T>& v) const
    {
        return f_(v.begin(), v.end());
    }
private:
    F f_;
};

template <typename T>
class test_v2
{
public:
  template <typename F>
  void set(F f)
  {
    f_ = holder<T,F>(f);
  }
  template <typename I>
  T call(I first, I last) const
  {
    return f_(std::vector<T>(first, last));
  }
private:
  std::function<T(const std::vector<T>&)> f_;
};
```

Answer (score 0):

Why not stoke the functor instead, something like:

```
template <typename T>
class test
{
public:
  template <typename I>
  auto call(I first, I last) const
   -> decltype(T()(first, last))
  {
    return T()(first, last);
  }
};
```

And use it:

```
test<sum<double>> t;
```

[Live example](http://ideone.com/0PIUCD)

Comment: Unfortunately, it doesn't work for my case as I need to store the functor as a member class since it is used in several methods.

Comment: @seg.fault: You may store `T` as member (add member, constructor, and change `T()` by the member).

Comment: I can't. The function can vary at runtime. For instance, `t.set(sum<double>()); t.call(v.begin(), v.end()); t.set(mean<double>()); t.call(v.begin(); v.end());`.